# HowTo set IsChecked Property false of all ToggleButtons in a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I list all existing ToggleButtons in a StackPanel and set its `IsChecked` Property to `false` in code-behind ?

I started with:

```
List<ToggleButton> togglebuttons = togglebtnListSp.Children.OfType<ToggleButton>().ToList();
        foreach(var item in togglebuttons)
        {
          item.IsChecked = false;  
        }
```

But now Im stuck and don't know how to confirm.

Here my XAML:

```
<!-- Private Customer Rights -->
<StackPanel x:Name="togglebtnListSp">
            <GroupBox x:Name="customerRightsGroupBox" Header="Customer Rights" Margin="10,10,10.2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="108">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can Add:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_add_customer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can Create Assignment:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_add_assignment_customer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can Delete:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_delete_customer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can Edit:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_edit_customer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <!-- Firm Customer Rights -->
            <GroupBox x:Name="firmCustomerRightsGroupBox" Header="Firmcustomer rights"  Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="108">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can Add:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_add_firmcustomer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can create Assignment for firmcustomer" DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontSize="12" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_add_assignment_firmcustomer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can Delete:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_delete_firmcustomer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                            <Label Content="Can edit:" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="can_edit_firmcustomer" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></ToggleButton>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
         </StackPanel>
```

I read false or true from database. But if i click on "Add" i want that all ToggleButtons are `IsChecked="false"`

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding it to a list, rather just create one linq command
which

creates the list FOR YOU and itterates it FOR YOU

```
YourStackPanel.Children
              .OfType<ToggleButton>().ToList()
                                     .ForEach(toggleButton => toggleButton.IsChecked = false);
```

Comment: I think this answer is better than my own as it lets Linq deal with the iteration and type checking.

Comment: It doesn't work for me (edited XAML Code above). Does it bug cuz before ToggleButton there is GroupBox etc. ? I think the ToggleButtons are still Childrens of the stackpanel.

Comment: @OJean, see previous comment. Probably meant to tag you instead of me.

Comment: @BernardWalters I get no Error. It just don't change the ToggleButtons IsChecked Property to false if i click my button.

Comment: @OJean what you asked for originally and what you now ask is different, you are going to have to recurse through all the decendants of the stackpanel and identify all the togglebuttons

Comment: @OJean, I reccomend rolling back your edits and asking a new question. You've basically invalidated all our answers by adding the nested children requirement way after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < togglebtnListSp.Children.Count; i++)
     if (_panel.Children[i] is ToggleButton)
              ((ToggleButton)_panel.Children[i]).IsChecked = false;
```

What's going on here is the code checks each child to see if it is a ToggleButton. If so, cast the UIElement object in the collection to a ToggleButton and set `IsChecked` to false.

Answer (score 0):

in code-behinde you can use a method to find all elements by type

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SeachUiElementsByTypo<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in SeachUiElementsByTypo<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Use like this:

```
var toggleButtons= UiServices.SeachUiElementsByTypo<ToggleButton>(YourWindow);
foreach (var tb in toggleButtons)
    ((ToggleButton)tb).IsChecked = false
```